# D3 Add Border to Bars on Graph

Tags: angularjs, typescript, d3.js

I just started with D3 this week.My project is written in Angular2 and TypeScript. I created a dynamic graph which getting values from user inputs. It is filled with gradient colors. I will like to outline or add border or stroke to my links whichever is a correct way of doing it. I was able to add "stroke" and "stroke-width" for my marker. I'm having problems with doing the same with my links.
Here is my marker code:

```
svg.selectAll('marker')
      .data(links)
      .enter().append('svg:marker')
      .attr('id', function (d) {
        return 'end-' + d.target;
      })
      .attr('orient', 'auto')
      .attr('refX', .1)
      .attr('refY', 0)
      .attr("viewBox", "0 -5 10 10")
      .attr("stroke", "black")
      .style("stroke-width", .1)
      .attr("fill", (d) => {
        return color(results.nodes[d.target].value);
      })
```

Here is my links code:

```
var link = svg.append("g")
      .attr("class", "links")
      .selectAll("path")
      .data(links)
      .enter().append('path')
      .attr("stroke", "black")
      .style("stroke-width", .1)
      .attr("d", (d) => {
        return this.makeLinks(d, results.nodes);
      })
      // .attr("fill", "black")
      // .style("stroke-width", .1)
      .style("stroke", (d, i) => {
        return "url(" + window.location + "#linear-gradient-" + i + ")";
      })
      // .attr("fill", "black")
      // .style("stroke-width", .1)
      .style("stroke-width", (d) => {
        return results.nodes[d.target].displaySize;
      })
      .attr("stroke", "black")
      .style("stroke-width", .1)
      .attr('marker-end', (d) => {
        return this.getEndMarker(d, results.nodes);
      })
```

;